# How to create .wav file from the amplitude data in python?

Tags: python, wav

I want to make the vibration wave to the audio file.

I can get the amplitude data from the .wav file.  but Now i have a series amplitude data that's not from the .wav file.  the data is as the following:

```
2013-02-12T02:58:00.047803  -1286
2013-02-12T02:58:00.097803  -1271
2013-02-12T02:58:00.147803  -1297
......
and so on ,200 datas per 1s.   

How do i change the datas into the .wav files  in python？
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `wave` module in combination with `pyaudio`. I am not sure though if it lets you create file with 200hz sampling frequency.  200hz sampling frequency can contain only < 100 Hz frequencies . That's not even good for lowest piano key